# Zip two flows in Akka Streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have two flows:

```
val a: Flow[Input, Data, NotUsed] =...
val b: Flow[Input, Unit, NotUsed] =...
```

The first flow is a stream of data events I care about, the second is a stream of "signals", that is I really only want to send a `Data` downstream when an element is received in `b`.

I thought of using something like `a.zipWith(b)((fromA, fromB) => fromA)` but that seems to work only between a flow and a source (despite the Akka documentation implying that it supports zipping flows too).

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the signatures of [`zip`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.22/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/zip.html) and [`zipWith`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.22/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/zipWith.html):

```
def zip[U](that: Graph[SourceShape[U], _]): Repr[(Out, U)]

def zipWith[Out2, Out3](that: Graph[SourceShape[Out2], _])(combine: (Out, Out2) => Out3): Repr[Out3]
```

both methods expect a `Source`.

Zipping a `Flow` with another `Flow` would not be as trivial as one might think (e.g. the 2nd `Flow` might be producing multiple elements per input element with [`mapConcat`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.22/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/mapConcat.html)).

You could consider building a custom `GraphStage` as shown in the following trivialized example:

```
case class DataIn(id: Int)
case class DataOut(content: String)
case class Signal(s: Int)

class ZipperFlow extends GraphStage[FlowShape[(DataIn, Signal), DataOut]] {

  val in = Inlet[(DataIn, Signal)]("ZipperFlow.in")
  val out = Outlet[DataOut]("ZipperFlow.out")

  override val shape = FlowShape.of(in, out)

  override def createLogic(attr: Attributes): GraphStageLogic =
    new GraphStageLogic(shape) {
      setHandler(in, new InHandler {
        override def onPush(): Unit = {
          push(out, DataOut("content-" + grab(in)._1.id))
        }
      })
      setHandler(out, new OutHandler {
        override def onPull(): Unit = {
          pull(in)
        }
      })
    }
}
```

Testing `ZipperFlow`:

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem("system")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
implicit val ec = system.dispatcher

val dataSource = Source(1 to 5).map(DataIn(_))
val signalSource = Source(1 to 5).map(Signal(_))

val sink: Sink[DataOut, Future[Done]] = Sink.foreach(println)

dataSource.zip(signalSource).via(new ZipperFlow).runWith(sink)

// DataOut(content-1)
// DataOut(content-2)
// DataOut(content-3)
// DataOut(content-4)
// DataOut(content-5)
```

Comment: Thanks, all that you say makes sense and my example is simplified, but I'm your code the thing I need to understand is not clarified: namely, how to zip two flows that are external to the stage I am building. In your example you have a single source that you split, but I would have two incoming sources. Also, I would like not to return ClosedShape but having this zipping stage as an element I can use in a bigger stream...

Comment: Another thing to note, while in my example I have used Input on both flows inputs, it's actually a different type in real life

Comment: @mdm, your use case is still a little unclear to me, but maybe the revised solution addresses some of your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
  implicit class FlowExt[In, Out, Mat](flow: Flow[In, Out, Mat]) {
    /**
     * 
     * @param f
     * @tparam Out2
     * @return
     */
    def zipFlow[Out2](f: Flow[In, Out2, Mat]): Flow[In, (Out, Out2), NotUsed] = {
      Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
        import GraphDSL.Implicits._

        val broadcast = b.add(Broadcast[In](2))
        val zip = b.add(Zip[Out, Out2])

        broadcast.out(0) -> zip.in0
        broadcast.out(1) -> zip.in1

        FlowShape(broadcast.in, zip.out)
      })
    }
  }
```

Usage, `val c: Flow[Input, (Data, Unit), NotUsed] = a.zipFlow(b)`

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved using [`merge`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Merge.html) in  [akka-streams graphs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-graphs.html#constructing-graphs)

update:
the correct one is [`zip`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Zip.html)

example:

```
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, ClosedShape}


object Application extends App {

  implicit val sys: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
  implicit val mat: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val flowX: Flow[Int, String, NotUsed] = Flow[Int].map(i => (i + 10).toString)
  val flowY: Flow[Int, Long, NotUsed] = Flow[Int].map(i => (i * 2).toLong)

  RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(flowX, flowY)((_, _)) { implicit builder =>
    (flowX, flowY) =>
      import GraphDSL.Implicits._
      val broadcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Int](2))
      val zip = builder.add(Zip[String, Long])
      Source((1 to 10).toList) ~> broadcast.in

      broadcast ~> flowX ~> zip.in0
      broadcast ~> flowY ~> zip.in1
      zip.out ~> Sink.foreach(println)
      ClosedShape
  }).run()
}
```

`flowX`&`flowY` are parameters for graph creation. in the [`constructing graph`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-graphs.html#constructing-graphs) part you can find different cases for spliting and merging the stream (fan-out + fan-in). working with graphs is a bit more harder than with linear flow. maybe it makes sense just to create a [partial graph](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-graphs.html#constructing-and-combining-partial-graphs) with flow shape (1 input, 1 output) - so the user will see it as a usual flow (but with the complexity hidden). personally i would suggest to try not to use graphs in general, because it's harder to test (it's harder to find an error there or performance degradation), although it's a great feature in some cases

you can find a lot of [methods](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/GraphDSL$.html) for graph creation with different amount of parameters. moreover you can provide different input params for graph creation - different sources, flow, sinks.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. `Merge` "picks randomly from inputs pushing them one by one to its output", I need an event to be emitted when there are events on both streams. Plus, my problem is that I can't see how to use those stages for two flows (as compared to two sources, for which there are more examples)

Comment: @mdm yes, you are right. merge picks one of, the correct one is zip/zipWith. https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Zip.html. but again, it's for graphs

Comment: If you could show an example of that in action, that would probably be what I need. I could not figure out how to use that with two existing flows.